# I have two data to render

Tags: django, python-3.x

Now I have two data to render: one is in 'base.html', and the other is in 'index.html'.I tried the following two methods, but none of them worked.

## views.py

```
def everyday_cs(request):
    r = Content.objects.filter(is_check=True)
    everyday_cs = random.choice(r)
    return render(request, 'base.html', locals())

def index(request):
    everyday_cs(request)
    articles = LifeArticle.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', locals())
```

## url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index,),
]
```

and

## testurl.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index,),
    url(r'^$', views.everyday_cs,),
]
```

## base.html

```
{{everyday_cs}}
```

## index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% if articles %}
{% for article in articles %}
{{article.title}}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I want to run the 'everyday_cs' function first when I run 'index' and 'url.py' write two 'url(r'^$', )' to run them, but they don't work.

Comment: You should use `context_processor` to pass variable when you want to use that variable in any template without regarding any view i.e in base.html or any other template.

Comment: `none of them worked` - please share error message or clarify in any other way what is happening. `render(request, 'index.html'...` -> `render(request, 'myapp/index.html'...`

Comment: No error messages,I want to put the value of 'everyday_cs' in the template

Comment: When I visit 'index.html', there is no 'everyday_cs' in 'base.html'.When I visit the index, what should I do if there is value in 'base.html'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, yesteraday night i'm coding answer appeared.this is my code.
Just need to add the field to be rendered in the 'index' views to work

views.py

```
def index(request):
    r = Content.objects.filter(is_check=True)
    everyday_cs = random.choice(r)
    articles = LifeArticle.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'articles': articles, 'everyday_cs': everyday_cs})
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index,),
]
```

base.html

```
{{everyday_cs}}
```

index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% if articles %}
{% for article in articles %}
{{article.title}}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

good,there is working,did not understand before.
Actually only used for rendering in view 'index'.